# MySql: order by along with group by - performance

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the performance problem with query that have `order by` and `group by`. I have checked similar problems on SO but I did not find the solution to this:(

I have something like this in my db schema:
`pattern` has many `pattern_file` belongs to `project_template` which belongs to `project`

Now I want to get `projects` filtered by some data(additional tables that I join) and want to get the result ordered for example by `projects.priority` and grouped  by `patterns.id`. I have tried many things and to get the desired result I've figured out this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `projects`.*  FROM `projects` 
INNER JOIN `project_templates` ON `project_templates`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id`
INNER JOIN `pattern_files` ON `pattern_files`.`id` = `project_templates`.`pattern_file_id`
INNER JOIN `patterns` ON `patterns`.`id` = `pattern_files`.`pattern_id`
 ...[ truncated ]
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT projects.id FROM `projects` INNER JOIN `project_templates` ON `project_templates`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id`
    INNER JOIN `pattern_files` ON `pattern_files`.`id` = `project_templates`.`pattern_file_id`
    INNER JOIN `patterns` ON `patterns`.`id` = `pattern_files`.`pattern_id`
    ...[ truncated ]
    WHERE [here my conditions]  ORDER BY [here my order]) P 
    ON P.id = projects.id 

WHERE [here my conditions]
GROUP BY patterns.id
ORDER BY [here my order]
```

From my research I have to `INNER JOIN` with subquery to conquer the problem "ORDER BY before GROUPing BY" => then I have put the same conditions on the outer query for performance purpose. The `order by` I had to use again in the outer query too, otherwise the result will be sorted by default.

Now there is real performance problem as I have about 6k `projects` and when I run this query without any conditions it takes about 15s :/ When I narrow the result by specify the conditions the time drastically dropped down. I've found somewhere that the subquery is run for every outer query row result which could be true when you watch at the execution time :/

Could you please give some advice how I can optimize the query? I do not work much with sql so maybe I do it from the wrong side from the very beginning?

P.S. I have tried WHERE projects.id IN (Select project.id FROM projects ....) and that discarded the performance issue but also discarded the ORDER BY before GROUPing BY

EDIT.

I want to retrieve list of `projects`, but I want also to filter it and order, and finally I want to get patterns.id unique(that is why I use the group by).

> order by in your inner query (p) doesn't make sense (any inner sort will only 
>   have an arbitrary effect).

@Solarflare Unfortunately it does. group by will take first row from grouped result. It preserve the order for join. Well, I believe that it is specific to MySql. Furthermore to keep the order from subquery I could use `ORDER BY NULL` in outer query :-)

> Also, select projects.* ... group by pattern.id is fishy (although MySQL, in contrast to every other dbms, allows you to do this)

so we can assume I retrieve only `projects.id`, but from docs:

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY to permit selecting fields that are not mentioned in the GROUP BY clause

Comment: `order by` in your inner query (`p`) doesn't make sense (any inner sort will only have an arbitrary effect). The inner query (which might be the cause of your slowness) seems to only exists because you *want* the order by, but the goal is unclear from your description; maybe an some sample data so we can fix it.

Comment: Also, `select projects.* ... group by pattern.id` is fishy (although MySQL, in contrast to every other dbms, allows you to do this). From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html): *the server is free to choose any value from each group, ... the values chosen are nondeterministic, which is probably not what you want.*). It is again not really clear what result you are trying to get here and/or how to fix it.